# bios interrupt and dos interuppt

Tags: bios

what is the difference between dos interuppt and bios interuppt

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13

Answer (score 2):

In 16-bit 80x86 programming, user programs communicate with system service using *interrupts*. Typically this takes the form of:

1. Loading a register (often AH) with a numeric function code
2. Loading any other registers with parameters as required by the function
3. Executing the `INT` instruction with an interrupt vector number

The BIOS offers its own services under a few different interrupt vector numbers, for example:

- INT 10h - video services
- INT 13h - disk services

DOS, since it is a separate component from the BIOS, offers its services under INT 21h.